# File upload on s3 : failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yii2

I have a problem to file upload on S3 aws.The file extension is .pdf. I receive request from FormData class AJAX.I handle file and upload s3. but something is wrong... can you ask me pls ?
Framework => Yii2...

Controller :

```
 public function actionUploadFile(){
    $path = \Yii::getAlias('@frontend/upload');
    $fileName = 'uploaded_file.pdf';
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $file = fopen($path.$fileName,'w');
    fwrite($file,$data);
    fclose($file);
    $model = new DocumentForm([
        'requestType' => DocumentRequestEnum::UPLOAD,
        'document_title' => 'test',
        'document_description' => 'test123',
        'service_provider_id' => 1,
        'file_name' =>$path.$fileName,
    ]);
    return $model->upload();
}

}
```

DocumentForm

```
$serviceProvider = ServiceProvider::findOne([
        'id' => $this->service->id,
    ]);

    $serviceProvider->file_name = $this->file_name;
    $serviceProvider->document_title = $this->document_title;
    $serviceProvider->document_description = $this->document_description;
    $serviceProvider->save(false);

    return \Yii::$app->awsDocument->uploadFile($this->file_name,'');
```

And bucketClass

```
public function uploadFile($name, $pathOnS3, $options = [])
{
    $params = [
        'Bucket'     => $this->bucket,
        'ACL'        => $this->acl,
        'Key'        => ($pathOnS3) ? $pathOnS3 : $this->basePath . basename($name),
        'SourceFile' => $name,
    ];

    $params = array_merge($params, $options);

    return $this->s3->putObject($params);
```

thks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be you need  directory separator

```
    $file = fopen($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName,'w');
```

.

```
    'file_name' =>$path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName,
```

Comment: thx, because of my directory and acl, i don't need exactly acl in this case...